# Nest.js injection of model?

Tags: nestjs

I have the follwoing code from tutorial|:

```
constructor(@InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>) {}
```

Where `User` is:

```
export interface User extends Document {
  readonly name: string;
  readonly age: number;
  readonly phone: string;
}
```

Could you explain how `@InjectModel` works, what is `'User'` and why we passed `Model<User>`, what does it mean?

What I can inject also using `@InjectModel`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All right, to get into this, first we have to take to truth that interfaces do not exist at runtime. So the `User` interface you have is only useful during development. I'll try to break this down step by step, starting from the end of the line and working backwards.

`Model<User>`: `Model` is an interface type exposed by `mongoose` that allows us to know that the model we're using has methods like `find` and `create`. By saying `Model<User>` we are saying "This is a mongoose model object that refers to the `User` interface. This is especially useful for Typescript because as the functions are typed with generics, it knows what the return of methods like `find` are: an array of `User` objects. The model interface is really `Model<T>` where `T` is the interface that extends `Document` (another `mongoose` type).

What is `'User'`: `'User'` is the string equivalent of the name of the interface. If your interface that extends `Document` is called `Dog` you use `'Dog'`, if it's `Animal` you use `'Animal'`. The reason for not passing the interface is because interfaces do not exist at runtime (unlike classes).

How does `@InjectModel()` work: Okay, the really fun part of the question to answer. Nest works normally by using Injection Tokens. Normally, these tokens are determined by the type of the injected value. In your case `Model<User>`. Now, the problem here is that A) interfaces don't exist at runtime and B) Typescript does not reflect generics well, so even if `Model` was a class, all that could be gotten would be `Model` which isn't enough information on what to inject. So the next logical step Nest takes is to allow a user to provide injection tokens and use the `@Inject()` decorator. You can do things like injecting an object this way (like package configuration information). Useful, but a bit hard to work with without building your own providers. Now steps in `@InjectModel()`. `@InjectModel()` builds an injection token based on the string that's passed into the function. This token is something along the lines of `typeModel` where `type` is actually what you pass into the function. This tells Nest specifically what model we are injecting. This also needs to align with the provider created with `MongooseModule.forFeature()`, hence why `name` and the value passed to `@InjectModel()` need to be aligned. Usually it's easiest to align when they use the same string name as the interface.